# How to install Node.JS (nvm) on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js

Simple question waiting for simple instruction that could be Ctrl+Ced Ctrl+Ved.
Hope STACK overflow will help me to simply install Node.JS.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions-enterprise-linux-fedora-and-snap-packages? https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
# Add repository for Node.js 13.x.
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash -

# Install Node.js 13.x.
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation or some more details to your answer, simply  adding two commands doesn't per say help understand OP or future community members the issue or the proposed solution.